# Outlook unable to access IMAP accounts due to "exhausting all resources"

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook-2019

All of a sudden this morning, I encountered this error when trying to navigate mail in Microsoft Outlook 2019:

[image]

This seems to affect **all** of my accounts *except* for the primary account, which is an Exchange account.

I did some research and came across tips like this one: https://www.msoutlook.info/question/518

However, I deleted an entire IMAP account from Outlook and the problem persisted, even after numerous restarts and ensuring the process had been killed. Up until this morning, everything had been working <s>fine</s> reasonably well so this has me puzzled. (I say reasonably fine because this is by no means the only headache that Outlook 2019 has given me.)

I primarily use the MailNews client for email, not Outlook, for email specifically, and I have no issue with my accounts in there, obviously, since it uses the MBOX format. Unsurprisingly, I don't encounter the issue with Outlook 2010 on Windows 7, either.

Is there a clear cause or fix for this? I'm really at my wits end with the newer versions of Office. Combining OST or PST files here is not an option. I have probably around 20 GB of email, so I don't want to purge all the caches or delete the accounts and add them again if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really satisfied with this finding, but an entire restart of Windows resolved the problem for me (at least for now). I'm guessing some service besides `outlook.exe` was killed in the process and a restart allowed Outlook to come online normally again without the strange exhaustion error.